# Count duplicate records from any table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which can check any table on duplicates. It returns a result set with all the duplicate rows from the given table.

What I want now is to count the amount of duplicates, get the table name & rundate query  and insert it into a table.

The problem I'm facing currently is that the SP returns a set with a variable amount of columns. Therefore I can't insert the result of the SP in a predefined temptable.

Does anyone know a (smarter) way to do this?

**Expected result**

|tableName|Date|sumDupRows|

**SP I'm using:**

```
create proc [dbo].[sp_duplicates] @table nvarchar(50) as

declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @groupby nvarchar(max)

set @groupby =  stuff((select ',' + name
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
                FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'select *, count(*) as duplicates
                from '+@table+'
                group by '+@groupby+'
                having count(*) > 1'

exec (@query)
GO
```

Comment: What do you mean MAXDATE?  If there are duplicates they'll all have the same date.  You'd need every column of every duplicated row.

Comment: Transform the result set to JSON or XML and store it.

Comment: @lotzinspace, corrected it; max date is supposed to be the run date (a getdate() will do the trick) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found duplicate records. Use another `select` to aggregate them.

```
create proc [dbo].[sp_duplicates] @table nvarchar(50) as

declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @groupby nvarchar(max)

set @groupby =  stuff((select ',' + name
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
                FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'SELECT ' +
                @table + ' AS tableName,
                GETDATE() AS MaxDate,
                SUM(duplicates) AS TotalDuplicates 
              FROM
              (
                select count(*) as duplicates
                from '+@table+'
                group by '+@groupby+'
                having count(*) > 1
              ) A'

exec (@query)
GO
```

Comment: the select @ table is required to be in between quotes (somehow i can't edit it ;)'SELECT ''' +
                @table + ''' will do the trick